# How to write a controller for validation of multipaged form?

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller, validation

I'm struggling with the proper organisation of a (MVC) Controller for my validation of a multipaged form. The problem is that I not only have to check whether the user input is existant at all, but I have to match it with different databases (depending on the field), too. I also need that database-data that results from the user-input for different view-options.

It's unclear for me where I should put that validation at all. I would like to put not too detailed things into the controller, but at the same time I don't like models using each other (without the controller).

Here's a basic example from a controller, the steps stand for different stages/pages of the form:

```
// GET VARIABLES FROM $_POST + $_GET
private function make_environment()
{
    // PUT ALL VARIABLES INTO ARRAY
    $vars = array();
    if(!empty($_GET)) { $values = array_merge($vars,$_GET); }    
    if(!empty($_POST)) { $values = array_merge($vars,$_POST); }

    // PUT ALLOWED VARIABLES INTO PROPERTY
    foreach($this->properties as $property)
    {
        if(isset($values[$property]))
        {
            $this->properties[$property] = htmlspecialchars(trim($values[$property]));
        }
    }

}


// HANDLE DATA


// PRODUCES DATA FOR VIEW    
private function set_data()
{
    $data = '';
    // CHOOSE DATA-OBJECT AND DATA-HANDLER
    switch($this->properties['step'])
    {
        case 1:
            // DATA HANDLER
            $handler = new calendar($this->properties);
            $data['calendar'] = $handler->return_data();
            break;

        case 2:
            // DATA HANDLER
            $handler = new form($this->properties);
            $data['form'] = $handler->return_data();
            break;
    }

    return $data;
}


// CREATE OR UPDATE VIEW

private function run_view($data)
{
    new view('header','');

    switch($this->properties['step'])
    {
        default:
            new view('chooser','');
            break;
        case 1:
            new view('calendar',$data['calendar'],$this->properties);
            break;

        case 2:
            new view('form',$data['form'],$this->properties);
            break;
    }

    new view('footer','');
}
```

At the moment the different 'handlers' (in `set_data()`) are querying the database, but prior to that I'd need a check whether the required fields have been submitted and whether those fields are valid (whether they exist in the database). I don't really know where to put that kind of validation. Propably in a separate model, but then I'd have to query the DB there **and** in the data-handler **again**. Maybe you got an idea ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue about the MVC you use, but I'd prefer something like this:

```
$form = new MultipageForm('BubblePagesForm');
$form->importFromSession($app->getSession());
if ($form->validates($app->getRequest()))
{
    $form->processRequest($app->getRequest());
    $form->exportToSession($app->getSession());
    $responseType = new SuccessfullFormRequest($form);
}
else 
{
    $responseType = new InvalidFormRequest($form);
}
$app->setResponse($responseType, array($form));
```

Comment: What if some mean person would try changing form data from already processed requests ? That would allow him to access a higher level of the form with wrong form data. Thing is that I can't use sessions, so I have to rely on post and get, which is easily manipulated.

Comment: @DanSurfrider: No, the state of the form is saved into the session. That's why there is `importFromSession` and `exportToSession`. The form knows when processing the request, to which page/step of the form the request belongs to. Previous data can not be changed client-side (only server-side inside the session store).

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I don't want to use sessions, so I have to rely on post and get unfortunately.

Comment: @DanSurfrider: Than you have always the problem you don't want to have. So either use server-side storage or client-side-storage. If you use client-side-storage for your session data, then it can be manipulated - always. Take care.